# Creating database with csv files in Rstudio

Tags: r, database, csv

I was trying to create a database, and when I looked it up online, I found this tutorial.
[here](https://datacarpentry.org/R-ecology-lesson/05-r-and-databases.html#Creating_a_new_SQLite_database)

The step it took was to use

```
my_db_file <- "data/portal-database-output.sqlite"
my_db <- src_sqlite(my_db_file, create = TRUE)
```

When I do `file.exists("database.sqlite")`, it prints `FALSE`. I was wondering if there's a way to get "database.sqlite" so I can finish creating this database? Is it from a package? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The file that you created with the first line was `portal-database-output.sqlite` under the `data/` directory. If you were to do,

```
file.exists("data/portal-database-output.sqlite")
```

then it should return `TRUE`.

You need to read in the data, create the database, then you can add your data to it.

```
library(tidyverse)
download.file("https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/3299483",
              "species.csv")
species <- read_csv("data/species.csv")

my_db_file <- "data/portal-database-output.sqlite"
my_db <- src_sqlite(my_db_file, create = TRUE)

copy_to(my_db, surveys)
```

Output

```
my_db

src:  sqlite 3.35.5 [portal-database-output.sqlite]
tbls: species, sqlite_stat1, sqlite_stat4

file.exists("data/portal-database-output.sqlite")

[1] TRUE
```